# yet another error_reporting not working

Tags: php, apache2

Okay so I did my research and found that if I want to see all errors on my webserver (apache2 on ubuntu) I have to edit the php.ini file, well... after looking in it (/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini) I found out that error_reporting is by default set to E_ALL and display_errors is by default On yet I still get a white page even after manually editing php.ini from apache2 and from cli... still white page.
But if I manually set error_reporting() in a single file it shows me the errors.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
```

What do I have to do so I can view php errors automatically in any file?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I have restarted apache2 after every edit.

Comment: Run `<?php phpinfo();` to inspect current settings, including php.ini location (to make sure you are editing the correct file) and local/master values for your error reporting directives.

Comment: Are you using some sort of CMS?

Comment: I've got it to work, I wasn't editing the right settings... I was editing in the comments section (LOL, I'm tired).

So for the lurkers, try finding the right setting to edit in php.ini.